# How to integrate FlotJs into ReactJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, flot

I am trying to integrate [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) charts into React but I get `$.plot` is not a function error, I have the following code

Script tags Index.html

```
<script src="dist/libs/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/libs/js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="dist/libs/js/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script src="dist/libs/js/jquery.flot.symbol.js"></script>
```

My React component

```
class OfferGraph extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={
      isLogged:false
    }

    //Test Code 
    let node = $('#trackInsightGraph');
    $.plot(node, [{
      data: data['searchAverage'],
      points: {show: false}
    }, {
      data: data['offer'],
      points: {show: false}
    }, {
      data: data['similar'],
      points: {show: false}
    }, {
      data: data['c01'],
      lines: {show: true}
    }], options);
  }

  render(){
    return <div id="trackInsightGraph">
    </div>
  }

}
export default OfferGraph;
```

I can't use another Chart library as most the functionality is written for [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) Please help, if some body can point out an example how these(Flot) jQuery plugins can be integrated into React

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code -- both the given and the unstated but assumed -- is that the constructor is going to be called first, before the chart container div is created in the `render()` function. And the constructor needs that container div. At least that's what I'm guessing based on the incomplete code given.

I created a jsfiddle that shows [how I would approach the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/JMBucknall/mqb4bxyh/). I'm using `React.createClass()` to create the component. Inside that, the `renderChart()` function is the actual drawing code and it uses a `ref` for the container that is created in the `render()` function.

Both the data for the chart and the options are passed in through the call to `ReactDOM.render()` at the bottom of the code. That call creates the container (placing it in another container) and the two props are passed in at that time.

(Note: I decided to not use JSX for this example. I leave the changes as an exercise for the reader.)